# PHP JavaScript Validation Error

Tags: javascript, php, html, form-submit

I thought I had this problems solved, but my issue is still happening.

Every time I click send, my form still sends.  I thought I had my JavaScript correctly validating the form, but it's not working because I can put anything in the email fields, and it still processes.  The alerts still work.  I just want to use PHP and JavaScript, no AJAX or anything.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'Voice4Autism Inquiry';

$FirstName = $_POST['fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['lname'];
$eMail = $_POST['email'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

Hi!<br /><br/>

My name is $FirstName $LastName.  I am interseted in your newsletter from Voice4Autism.  Please add $eMail to your listserve.<br /><br />

Thank you,<br />
$FirstName $LastName

EMAIL;

$header = "From: $eMail\r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
}
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkforblank() {
    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('fname').value ==""){
        errormessage += "enter your first name \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('lname').value ==""){
        errormessage += "enter your last name \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('email').value ==""){
        errormessage += "enter your email \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value ==""){
        errormessage += "confirm your email \n";
    }

    if (errormessage != ""){
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
    } else return true;
}

function verifyEmail() {
    var status = false;     
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    if (document.myForm.email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
              alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
              return false;
    }


    if (document.getElementById('email').value == document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value) {
        alert("Thank you for your interest!");
            return true;              
    } else {
        alert("Email addresses do not match.  Please retype them to make sure they are the same.");
        return false;
    }

    return status;
}

function confirmEmailAddresses(){
    if (checkforblank() == true) {
        if (verifyEmail() == true) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
<table width="377" height="96" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">First Name:</td>
    <td><label for="FirstName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Last Name:</td>
    <td><label for="LastName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Confirm E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="confirmEmail" id="confirmEmail"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="confirmEmailAddresses()"><input type="reset" value="Reset Form"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Could u post form HTML please. Thanks

Comment: I did today!  Sorry for the delay!

Comment: Thanks! I have put an answer below! I hope it helps?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<script>
function checkforblank() {
    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('fname').value ===""){
        errormessage += "enter your first name \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('lname').value ===""){
        errormessage += "enter your last name \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('email').value ===""){
        errormessage += "enter your email \n";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value ===""){
        errormessage += "confirm your email \n";
    }

    if (errormessage !== ""){
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
    } 
    else{return true;}
}

function verifyEmail() {
    var status = false;     
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var email_reg = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if (!email_reg.match(emailRegEx)) {
              alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
              return false;
    }


    else if (document.getElementById('email').value !== document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value) {
        alert("Email addresses do not match.  Please retype them to make sure they are the same.");
            status = false;            
    } else {
        alert("Thank you for your interest!");
        status = true;
    }

    return status;
}

function confirmEmailAddresses(){
    if((checkforblank())&&(verifyEmail())){return true;}else{return false;}


}
```

And call this function like this:

```
<form name="a" method="post" onSubmit="return confirmEmailAddresses()" action="xyz.html" id="a">
```

Comment: And it still sends blank forms if not filled out at all.

Comment: @user2638775 where exactly are you calling "confirmEmailAddresses()" ?

Comment: The call is in the JavaScript and then it is attached to the "Submit" button.

Comment: try the code i have posted, you just have to change the name of the form in yur code, as in my code the name of the form is "a"

Comment: @user2638775: do let me know if you face any issues using my code.  I'll be available after 6 hrs from now ")

Comment: Hey there.  The code is not in not working.  I have to links on my test server for this:

http://jtest.isnanmx.com/contact.php
http://jtest.isnanmx.com/contactA.php

ContactA is not popping up anything, nor does it send anything.  Contact is sending blank forms and/or not validating.

Comment: Sadly, i can put anything in the email fields and it won't validate, even though it 'does'

Comment: @user2638775: Oh that's weird, at my end its working well, here's the link check yourself.http://unizhost.com/a/testd/index.html

Comment: I'm testing the code.  I'll let you know how it goes by tomorrow...about 18 hours or so.  Hope to be in touch!

Comment: Edit:  There is an extra popup that comes up and when I add the PHP code, it does not process.  :-\

Comment: @user2638775: yes there is but only in the code that i used on my server that can be easily deleted. the code i posted here in stack doesn't have that popup. yes i'll be in touch.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `onClick` event from the submit button, and add `return confirmEmailAddresses();` to the `onsubmit` event of the main form element.

Make sure that the `confirmEmailAddresses()` function has the line `return true;` if the validation passes! Else `return false;`.

Comment: I've done all of this with no success.  :(  I appreciate your help though.  This is the code I have:


function confirmEmailAddresses(){
 if (checkforblank() == true) {
  if (verifyEmail() == true) {
   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   return false;
  }
 } 
}


I also have:
function confirmEmailAddresses(){
    if((checkforblank())&&(verifyEmail())){return true;}else{return false;}

Comment: Instead of "document.getElementById("myForm").submit();" try just using "return true;". If you make the function call "onsubmit" as described above, ensuring it says "return confirmEmailAddress();" the form is now expecting true or false to be returned. Sorry i overlooked this before!

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
return false;
```

after each of your alert() calls.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!  I shall try it.  Just some clarification...after *each* of my alert calls?  The form submits fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

Comment: So I tried "return false" but it makes it not work in any browser now.  Any other suggestions?  I do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what you want? If the form is not valid, you want to show the alert and not submit the form, right?

It might help to see the html form where you're calling confirmEmailAddresses()

Comment: The invalid form is sending in Safari only.  It's quite odd!  I appreciate the help!  I'm still working on it!